# Postgresql table's files

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

I have a question about  "Item related to the table".

There are three files per table (OID, OID_fsm, OID_vm). But when I created a user table (`test_tbl`) then I see only 1 file (OID) in base director (not specific tablespace).

So when will the other files (oid_fsm,oid_vm) be created?

```
[path]/base/12780
32813      32813_fsm  32813_vm --an old table
58117    --This only 1 file (oid) for table test_tbl
```

[image]

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/storage-file-layout.html - I guess after some updates.

Comment: I identified that after  I insert more data row (10001rows ) then the OID (57984_fsm) was created, so mean that OID_fsm is about space ( file to manage table free space)and OID_vm  I think it will create for managing the visibility of the table block.

Comment: Thank Pavel Horal. you gave me the hint